# Running ASP.net application on IIS - timeout error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I was running my asp.net application on localhost in the internal IIS for Visual Studio and for Testing purposes I was trying to host my website on my LAN at home. I obviously had to switch to use the custom IIS web server. I followed all the steps to do this i.e. I turned on IIS from the windows features in control panel and added my web application to IIS and configured VS settings to use that server and gave it a start URL.

However when I run my project I am getting an error message:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server did not
>   respond in a timely    manner. This may be because another debugger is
>   already attached to the web server.

What is the cause of this error and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Is visual studio and the IIS instance on the same box.

Comment: what do you mean on the same box? I set Visual studio to Use Custom Web Server and gave it http://localhost/appname as the URL. Also, I gave it a start URL for my home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to make an empty page and you call the debugger from it as

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

To solve it and make possible to start the debugger from the VS you must configure the start up page to see the local IIS on the properties of your project. Also I have notice that if you do not have default browser the IE it may also fail. So for me, to move on, call the debugger from the page.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I solved it by reseting iis from [cmd](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/visual-studio-unable-to-start-debugging.html) => "`iisreset`"