# Visual Studio unable to start debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis

Every time I build my solution and try to start debugging, I get this message:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server did not respond on a timely manner. This maybe another debugger is attached to the web server.

If I restart my IIS, I can start debugging but If I build again I have to restart my IIS again. I saw several people having same issue but no one same as mine exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Open your cmd in administrator mode and run cmd

```
iisreset
```

Answer (score 0):

The below link contain some useful answers:

[Unable to start debugging on the web server. Could not start ASP.NET debugging VS 2010, II7, Win 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653236/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-could-not-start-asp-net-debugging-v)

Like this answer:

1)

> Try going to IIS and checking to make sure the App Pool you are using
>   is started. A lot of times, you will produce an error that shuts down
>   the app pool. You just need to right click and Start and you should be
>   good to go.

2) And this answer

> Turns out that the culprit was the IIS Url Rewrite module. I had
>   defined a rule that redirected calls to Default.aspx (which was set as
>   the start page of the web site) to the root of the site so that I
>   could have a canonical home URL. However, apparently VS had a problem
>   with this and got confused. This problem did not happen when I was
>   using Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite so it didn't even occur to me to check.
>
> I ended up creating a whole new web site from scratch and porting
>   projects/files over little by little into my solution and rebuilding
>   my web.config until I found this out! Well, at least now I have a
>   slightly cleaner site using .NET 4.0 (so far, hopefully I won't run
>   into any walls)--but what a pain!

Comment: If it helps, I have experimented a little with App Pool. When I switch my application to different Application Pool I'm usually able to start debugging but again if rebuild I have to either reset IIS or change app pool

Comment: can you try solving the issue with the following advised answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327188/running-asp-net-application-on-iis-timeout-error